# disable alarm using alarm ARN

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

According to the documentation, I can use Python to disable alarms like this. However, this option only gives the AlarmNames parameter. I want to disable alarms using ARNs.

```
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
disable_alarm = client.disable_alarm_actions(AlarmNames=[name])
```

One option could be to use the ARN to first get the name and then disable it using the name. But how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

If there really is no other option, you may need to query all alarms with `client.describe_alarms()` or an equivalent paginator, and iterate over them until you find one with a matching ARN.

The following example lists all AlarmArn => AlarmName associations in `us-east-1`:

```python
    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name="us-east-1")
    client = session.client("cloudwatch")
    nextToken = {}
    while True:
        result = client.describe_alarms(MaxRecords=100, **nextToken)
        if 'MetricAlarms' in result:
            for alarm in result['MetricAlarms']:
                print("{} => {}".format(alarm['AlarmArn'], alarm['AlarmName']))
        if 'CompositeAlarms' in result:
            for alarm in result['CompositeAlarms']:
                print("{} => {}".format(alarm['AlarmArn'], alarm['AlarmName']))
        if 'NextToken' in result:
            nextToken = {'NextToken': result['NextToken']}
        else:
            break
```

[Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.describe_alarms)